# How to divide a region in FEM with a parametric curve?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, parametric-functions, mesh

I'm using `NDSolve` with finite element to try to solve a heat transfer problem. The region I have is a rectangle where the four vertices are at `(-0.5,0)`, `(0.5,0)`, `(0.5, 3)`, `(-0.5,3)`. The rectangle is divided into two regions (different thermal conductivity) by a parametric curve `y=1-0.1*Cos[2*pi*x]`, where `-0.5<=x<=0.5`. There is an example similar to this case in the official [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html) using `ToBoundaryMesh`, but the region is divided by a straight line, not a curve. I also tried something like

```
ir = ParametricRegion[{t, 1 + \[Delta] Cos[2 \[Pi] t]}, {{t, -0.5, 0.5}}]
coords = DiscretizeRegion[ir]
```

But then I'm not sure how to supply the coordinates to `ToBoundaryMesh` or other functions.

How can I generate the mesh for use in `NDSolve`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
(* If you do not have the FEMAddOns installed get then with: *)
(*  ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][] *)

Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
(* Create Regions *)
dom = Rectangle[{-0.5, 0}, {0.5, 3}];
bot = DiscretizeRegion@
   ImplicitRegion[(-0.5 <= x <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 
       1 + 0.1 Cos[2 \[Pi] x]), {x, y}];
bmesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[dom];
bmesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[bot];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bmesh1, bmesh2]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Curved Internal Boundary]

Comment: I think this is a good approach.

Comment: If I want to apply periodic boundary condition to the left and right sides (`x=-0.5` and `x=0.5`), do I need to specify anything in the mesh generation stage, or do I just specify that in side `NDSolve`? I'm not sure if the generated mesh on the two sides actually match.

Comment: @Physicist I don't think _Mathematica_ requires a 1 to 1 nodal correspondence for PeriodicBCs as other codes do.